# HTML form never calls Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons defined in HTML like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="group" id="rad1" value="rad1" onClick="doStuff(this.id)">Option 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group" id="rad2" value="rad2" onClick="doStuff(this.id)">Option 2<br>
```

Just before the `</body>` tag, I have the following JavaScript behavior defined:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       /*<![CDATA[*/                   
       function doStuff(var id){
           alert("Doing stuff!");
       }
       /*]]>*/
   </script>
```

When I run the program, the page loads as expected in my browser window and the radio buttons allow me to click them. The `doStuff()` function, however, is never called (I validated this using breakpoints as well).

I also tried the following just to see if inline made the difference, but it seems the JavaScript is never called at all:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       /*<![CDATA[*/   
       alert("JavaScript called!");
       main();
       function main(){
            var group = document.getElementsByName('group');
                for(var i=0; i<group.length; i++){
                    group[i].onclick = function(){
                        doStuff(this.id);
                    };
                }
       }
       /*]]>*/
</script>
```

My question is, is there something special I need to do using HTML and JavaScript in this context? My question is **not** whether I should be using inline function calls or whether this is your favorite way to write code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function declaration is bad -- there shouldn't be a "var" there before the parameter:

```
function doStuff (id) {
   alert("Doing stuff!");
}
```